# Show dropdown menu using external control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make a Bootstrap dropdown appear when an ajacent button is pressed?

I have tried every combination of:

```
$('#branchToggle').trigger('click.bs.dropdown').dropdown('toggle');
$('#branchToggle').parent().addClass('open')
$('#branchToggle').next().show()
```

But I can't get it to  work.

My html is:

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button id="activeBranchFilterBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-149">Branch</button>
                <button id="branchToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul id="branchFilter" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <?PHP foreach ($branchList as $branchData) { ?>
                        <li data-branch-id="<?PHP echo $branchData->id;?>" data-branch-name="<?PHP echo $branchData->name;?>"><a href="#"><?PHP echo $branchData->name;?></a></li>
                    <?PHP } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

---

To clarify, I want the list to show if the "Branch" button is pressed, just like it would if I clicked the normal trigger button.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L7JBz/) (http://jsfiddle.net/L7JBz/) what you are looking for?  It is a default feature of bootstrap,  just include `bootstrap.js` after `jquery.js`.  If this is not what you want,  I'm probably unable to understand your question.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Hi, no. When I click the branch button the list doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the drop-down to open only on click of the "Branch" button,  do something like this

```
$('#activeBranchFilterBtn').on("click", function(){
                    $('ul.dropdown-menu').toggle();
                });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7JBz/1/)

If you would like to get the drop-down when clicked anywhere on the complete block(either of the buttons),  do this

```
$('.btn-group').on("click", function(){
                    $('ul.dropdown-menu').toggle();
                });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7JBz/2/)

I guess the second one is what you need.

**UPDATE:** `class="open"` will be toggled on your `.btn-group` when a dropdown trigger is given from the button with `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute.  just add this attribute to the first button(Branch) and you will be good to go.  Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7JBz/3/).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a better way to close it than having to have to create a document click listener? I see the 'open' class is appended to the btn-group normally, but it won't apply this class when I click the branch button for some reason.

Comment: Not clear... do you mean you do not want to click again to close the drop-down?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "better way to close it than having to have to create a document click listener".  I think I got you r other concern.  `class="open"` is not being appended to the parent div on clicking the button called "Branch" because you didn't give it the attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"`.  Try the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7JBz/3/).